# Unable to obtain UUID (sub) of a User during Signup: Amazon Cognito

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to signup the user using AWS Cognito.

I understand from the signup method shown in [these docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#signUp-property) that the signup method's callback returns `err and data` and data parameter shall have usersub or UUID (e.g of UUID: 671fff45-77aa-4867-b11f-47c8bfa246a9).
I am unable to call the method (data.UserSub) to retrieve it, swift throws an error

> Value of type 'AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse' has no member
>   'UserSub'

See 3rd print statement in `SignUp()` to understand the full context.

```
class Login: UIViewController{
    var pool: AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       let AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey = "UserPool"
        self.pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.init(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)

       signUp()

    }

}


func signUp(){

    let userNameValue = "+" + UserData.mobileNumberWithCountryCode
        print("userNameValue: \(userNameValue)")
    let passwordValue = "somePassword" 

        var attributes = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType]()

    self.pool?.signUp(userNameValue, password: passwordValue, userAttributes: attributes, validationData: nil).continueWith {[weak self] (task) -> Any? in

    guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    print("Returninig nil on Strong Self")
                    return nil
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if let error = task.error as? NSError {

                        print("There is an error")

                    }else if let result = task.result  {
                        // The above line prints userName
                        print("userName after sub:\(result.user.username)") 

                       //the below line throws a swift error: Value of type 'AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse' has no member 'UserSub'
                       print("userName after sub:\(result.UserSub)")

               }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the SDK are you using?  If you are using a recent version likely you just have the casing wrong, it should be `.userSub`
see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderSignUpResponse.html#//api/name/userSub

Comment: Here are the SDK versions for iOS that I am using:`pod 'AWSCore', '~> 2.5.0'`
`pod 'AWSCognitoIdentityProvider', '~> 2.5.0'`

Comment: How can I also obtain the `userSub` when the user signs in.

Comment: The easiest way is to call the `getDetails` method on the user object.

Comment: When I print `self.user` ahead of `getDetails()` in SignIn method, I get `Optional(<AWSCognitoIdentityUser: 0x60c00025af10>)`, During signIn the below code does not go through, can you please suggest how I can get userSub ?`self.user?.getDetails().continueOnSuccessWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in     self.response = task.result
                
                print("self.response :\(self.response)" )                                              return nil
            }`

Comment: self.user?.getDetails().continueOnSuccessWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in
            for attribute in (task.result?.userAttributes)! {
                if(attribute.name == "sub"){
                    print("userSub: \(attribute.value!)")
                }
            }
            return self;
        }

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the code inside the block doesn't run i.e. `{ (task) -> AnyObject? in for attribute in (task.result?.userAttributes)! { if(attribute.name == "sub"){ print("userSub: (attribute.value!)") } } return self; }`

Comment: I added that code to the sample on github on line 79 of this file: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Swift/CognitoYourUserPoolsSample/UserDetailTableViewController.swift#L79 and it runs fine.

Comment: Here is a code that always works (https://gist.github.com/prahaladm/c0e7cb3838928d060a76a49b6d70babc) and here is a code that only works some times  i.e. the code inside the `getDetails` block doesn't get executed (https://gist.github.com/prahaladm/72dfc59bf84c0cd2b42d83771f5f2ddd). Would be good to know why this is happening.